# Laravel: Transform JSON response data

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Currently, I am returning data like so (basic example):

```
public function index()
{
    return User::all();
}
```

However, I want to wrap my responses with some extra meta data, so that they look something like:

```
{
    'success': true,
    'data': {
       ... // Normal response
     }
}
```

The success value would be something as simple as `statusCode == 200`.

I've read about using response macros, response factories, after middlewares, the Fractal library etc

Ideally it will work with all responses, e.g. returning Eloquent Models and Collections, as well as with `Response::json($data)`.

What is the best / right way, at the time of Laravel 5.2, to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're developing a API for Laravel, I'd recommend checking out [Dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api). It is one of the most useful package for developing APIs. Dingo uses Fractal to transform the responses. In your application to add such metadata, you could use [Transformers in Dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Transformers). There are also a lot of events that you can listen to and modify your data. In your particular example, `ResponseWasMorphed` would be one of the event that you would listen to.

If you want to continue with your project without adding external package, you can override the `response()` method in your `BaseController` which could check and add the needed.

```
public function response($data, $status)
{
    //calculate parameter based on $status
    $success = ...
    return response(array_merge($data, ['success' => $success]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid more dependencies for Dingo does look ideal for this and the other things I'll be needing. If not, your other solution should do the trick.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't automatically wrap `Response::json()` and returned Eloquent models

Comment: If you use the facade, it will not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fractal package for that. Then you can run the response through a transformer and get the proper response. Here's the package for that. https://packagist.org/packages/league/fractal

Comment: I was wanting a solution that basically says "if response type is json, wrap it with *this*", rather than having to change every response manually

Comment: Sure, but that's what transformers are for. I don't think your approach is possible in Laravel... Maybe i'm wrong :D